# MATLAB software for graph theory

Tags: graph-theory, matlab

I'm currently working on an undergraduate thesis that requires the use of graph theory(shortest path problem) in MATLAB. However, all the graph functions that I see in the MATLAB help bar do not make use of square grids. I am currently using the graphtraverse function for traversal by following adjacent nodes.

Is there any way where I can convert all the nodes into square grids?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need something that you cannot find in MATLAB / official toolboxes it is a good idea to check out the MATLAB exchange (http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/fileexchange).

For graph theory there is for example the following toolbox available (http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4266)

Peter

Answer (score 0):

See here, how graph theory can be used to segment retinal boundaries in optical coherence tomography (OCT) images, with the full MATLAB code and explainations: 
[Segmentation of Retinal Layers in OCT images with Graph Theory](http://imageprocessingblog.com/segmentation-of-retinal-layers-in-oct-images-with-graph-theory/)
(Includes finding the shortast path)

Comment: link above is broken, here is the working link to fileexchange. https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/43518-graph-based-segmentation-of-retinal-layers-in-oct-images disclaimer, i am the author.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add this toolbox also:

http://strategic.mit.edu/downloads.php?page=matlab_networks